# How can I make a line plot using a period of time as argument in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I'm pretty new to python and I've been trying unsuccessfully to do a plot where I would have something like

```
sns.lineplot(data=Ventes_df, x=month, y=ca_mensu, hue=year)
```

where

```
month = Ventes_df["date"].dt.to_period("M")
ca_mensu = Ventes_df.groupby(month)["price"].sum()
```

every time I try to run this it returns "RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Period', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects return Index.union(this, other, sort=sort).astype(object, copy=False)"
I'm not sure of what it means or how to do my plot.

Comment: You could try to convert the column to string format: `month = Ventes_df["date"].dt.to_period("M").astype(str)`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've checked, and "month" has indeed been converted but I have the same warning.

Comment: I use VScode and it seems to import pandas 1.2.4 and seaborn 0.11.1 by default

Comment: If the "month" has been converted to string, it's hard to get a `RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Period'`. Maybe `year` is also in `Period` format, also waiting to be converted?

Comment: I tried to convert 'year' as a string but then the error message was ```ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 0```

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin plot function if you are working in pandas dataframe.

pandadataframe.plot( 'Time/day' , 'value on y-axis' )

Comment: Thank you for your response, still, it didn't work since neither "month" or "ca_mensu" are in my data frame's columns

Comment: @Atik  You could do `Ventes_df["Time/day"] = month` to add a new column to the dataframe.

Comment: Even with month added in the dataframe, ca_mensu won't be and I cannot add a column for this one